# не получается отправить корректный post запрос

Tags: java, http, httpclient

Здравствуйте, есть сайт, на который нужно отправить post запрос, значение параметра там меняется с каждым запросом, подскажите, что не так я делаю ?

```
  HttpGet httpGet2 = new HttpGet(url);

        response = httpclient.execute(httpGet2);

        String html = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

        String value = new ParseHTML(html).parse(); 

        // value = 095assroESDNLTNsgg70BlL

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        List<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", value));

        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params1, "UTF-8"));
        response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        html = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

        value = new ParseHTML(html).parse();  
        // value = gJD3RUPpsBZhO7pCqYH
```

Comment: А что вы ожидаете получить?. Или в чем проблема?. С виду все хорошо

Comment: @НикитаВасильченко на сайте есть кнопка, при нажатии отправляется пост запрос, который я пытаюсь сделать, при запросе с этим кодом кнопка не нажимается. Следовательно у меня подозрение, что может быть дело в том, что когда я отправляю get запрос значение параметра одно, а при создании пост запроса оно меняется?